# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging multiple Projects

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have multiple Projects in my VS2012 Solution.

One of them (C#) uses assemblies of another Project (C++/CLI).

I can debug the C# project. But I can't set any breakpoints in my C++/CLI project in code that is called in the C# project.

I checked that the debugging information is created.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Native Code Debugging?

Try going to Project > Properties > Debug and tick 'Enable Native Code Debugging', and then save.